# Ajax xmlhttprequest with POST to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hello guys I am kina new in ajax and I have an issue, I want to call a php file to do some db queries from the javascript file. JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".delete").click(function(){
var xhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
       xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        $(".delete").css("color", "pink");
    }
};
    xhttp.open("POST","../admin-tasks/admin-delete-appointment.php",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("date="+date+ "&hour="+time);
});
});
```

And php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../connection.php");
if($_SESSION["password"]!=null) 
{   
if(!empty($_POST["date"]) && !empty($_POST["hour"])){
    $_SESSION["msg"]= "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('The appointment has been removed!');</script>";
    $date=$_POST["date"];
    $hour=$_POST["hour"];
...
```

I would like to point that the request is going properly, the php file is running if I sent data through html form with post,the problem is when I try it through the js file. The status is 200 and the readyState is going to 4 eventually. Is this below right when I call it from js??

```
$_POST["date"] 
$_POST["hour"]
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: open/send should not be inside onreadystatechange.  You appear you be using jQuery which has nice wrappers for this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The open send Is not inside the onreadystatechange, It is just the $("."delete), the question is is it any mistake on $_POST["date"]?? do I need to add something else to receive the data from xml with POST?? Cause the php file is correct when I call it from html form with POST but when I try to call it from AJAX with POST the db query is not fullfiled

Comment: `xhttp.send("date="+date+ "&hour="+time);` - where do you get `date` and `time` from?

Comment: Get it from a table, those variables are not null I tested it, I even tried xhttp.send("date="+String(date)+ "&hour="+String(time));
But nothing. I believe for some reason in php file the variables that are getting the $_POST are null, cause I see no changes in the database. But the code in php its right if I call it from an html form with POST.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add some brackets ?

```
if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
    $(".delete").css("color", "pink");
    xhttp.open("POST","../admin-tasks/admin-delete-appointment.php",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("date="+date+ "&hour="+time);
}
```

Comment: Okay I edited the code here again, Its not the problem on brackets, I believe that the problem must be around php file when I try to receive the data with POST when I call it from js file and not with a typical html form...

Answer (score 0):

The code is completely right, I found the mistake on method date. If I give date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) and the var $date instead of - has / or w/e it wont change the date to the format you expect.